# TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable python3

Tags: python, discord

I'm just making discord bot with python3

```
    if message.content.startswith('!meal'):
        with open('menu.json', encoding='utf-8') as json_file:
            data = json.load(json_file)
        channel = message.channel
        await channel.send('this is meal info!')
        await channel.send(data())
```

but I got errors when I used this command

```
~/pythonruby/discord bot/main.py", line 30, in on_message
    await channel.send(data())
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

this errors.. I tried make data to dict..

Comment: As far as I know, you can only send strings, so try making the data a multi-line string.

Comment: In the menu.json what exactly are you trying to send, the whole thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always send the dict as a string like this

```
await channel.send(str(data))
```

But... that may not be the friendliest representation of the data.

Comment: I'm trying to send specific date with data info not whole data so I want to make this dict that python can easily find and output it.

Comment: Id suggest reading this https://realpython.com/python-dicts/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are treating as a callable the returned value of `json.loads`. Check [this table](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json-to-py-table) to see what are the possible values you could get from.

I just reviewed the `discord` [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=send#discord.User.send), and you are supposed pass a string as the first parameter, so you do not need to treat `data` as a callable since after running `json.loads` you will probably have a string.

The following line will probably solve your problem:

```py
await channel.send(data)
```

However, in any case `data` is something different than a string, you will need to cast it:

```py
await channel.send(str(data)) # or f"{data}"
```